# How can we use "Validation groups" and "Render Web Resources Inline" in MS CRM portals?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

What is the use of **Validation group** and **Render Web Resources Inline** in MS Dynamics CRM portal's Entity Form ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Validation Group` and `Render Web Resources Inline` are additional settings in portal entity form configuration.

> **ValidationGroup**:   The group name assigned to input controls for evaluating valid input of named groups.

If you set this in entity form configuration, then in case if you are doing some custom validation in client side using js, Validation Group can be specified in custom validator. [Read more](http://arpitmscrmhunt.blogspot.com/2017/01/client-side-validation-using-javascript.html)

> **RenderWebResourcesInline**: CRM wraps Web Resources in an iframe by default. Set to "true", indicates that Web Resources should be rendered without an iframe.

This is to tell platform to differentiate as the same form is rendering in CRM platform & Portal as well. CRM will render HTML webresource inside IFRAME, which we don't need in Portal side.

[MS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/load-form-step) & [AdXstudio Reference](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/web-controls/crmentityformview/)